# Fastest way to count lines in file in MATLAB (Perl faster than C?)

Tags: c++, c, performance, perl, matlab

I have to count the number of lines in 10+ GB csv files in my research. The classic way of doing this on MATLAB seems to be using `textscan()` with `\n` as the delimiter, but that has a huge memory footprint and is awfully slow. I was advised to write a Perl script and call it using `str2double(perl('countlines.pl', path))`, which does seem significantly faster:

```
# countlines.pl
while (<>) {};
print $.,"\n";
```

Then, I wanted to see if I had any advantage by writing a MEX function that does the same in C, but had no luck, and more surprisingly, I found that this was about 10x slower than the Perl script (using the LLVM compiler on Xcode 4.6.3):

```
//countlines.c

#include "mex.h"

void countlines(char *filepath, double *numLines)
{
    /* Routine */

    numLines[0] = 0;
    FILE *inputFile = fopen(filepath, "r");
    int ch;

    while (EOF != (ch=getc(inputFile)))
        if ('\n' == ch)
            ++numLines[0];
}

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    /* Gateway function */

    int bufferLength, status;
    char *filepath;                 // Input: File path
    double *numLines;               // Output Number of lines

    bufferLength = (mxGetM(prhs[0]) * mxGetN(prhs[0])) + 1; // Get length of string
    filepath = mxCalloc(bufferLength, sizeof(char)); // Allocate memory for input

    // Copy the string data from prhs[0] into a C string
    status = mxGetString(prhs[0], filepath, bufferLength);
    if (status != 0)
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("utils:countlines:insufficientSpace", "Insufficient space, string is truncated.");

    // Create the output matrix and get a pointer to the real data in the output matrix
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,(mwSize)1,mxREAL);
    numLines = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    // Call the C routine
    countlines(filepath, numLines);
}
```

So,

1. Where is this overhead coming from in the MEX function besides the gateway function?
2. Is there anything else I can do to make this faster? I'm open to using any language so long as we can get the routine to interface with MATLAB. It seems the only other approach is to memory-map chunks of the file and split the workload across a few cores.

Comment: On linux you could use the system command `wc -l < filename`.

Comment: As suggested by PetrH, did you try calling it within MATLAB with [`system`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/system.html)?

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much. I tried `[~,output] = unix(strcat('wc -l < ', path)); numLines = str2double(output);` which is slightly faster than the Perl approach. I encapsulated this in a `if isunix` block and kept the Perl approach under the `else` block. :)

Comment: `wc -l` is definitely the way to go if Matlab is slow at doing it natively, though `strcat('wc -l < ', path)` will fail if the file name contains spaces or any other shell meta characters. You'll need to convert the path to a literal first. The code you need is the Matlab equivalent of `die if $path =~ /\0/; $path =~ s/'/'\\''/g; $path = "'".$path."'";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read Perl's FAQ on this subject, which give about 6 examples?

[perldoc -q 'How do I count the number of lines in a file'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file?)

The `wc` command has been ported to Windows, so that may be the best solution, if you want to install it.  Otherwise I'd go with the Perl example (fixed and optimized below) just prior to the `wc` example.

```
    my $lines = 0;
    open my $fh, '<:raw', $filename
        or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
    while( sysread $fh, $buffer, 64*1024 ) {
        $lines += ( $buffer =~ tr|\n||; );
    }
    close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. I tried this implementation and it was strangely actually about 20-40% slower than the simple count with the diamond operator for file sizes from 200 to 600 MB. However, I'll accept your answer as I agree that the use of `wc` is the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is this overhead coming from in the MEX function besides the gateway function?

1. The MEX function is allocating memory.
2. The function is converting the memory to a string.
3. The function is creating a matrix of doubles.

*No comparison to the simple line counting function of Perl, since they are not functionally equivalent.*

> Is there anything else I can do to make this faster?
>   Yes, only count lines.
>   No extra things, like reading in matrix of doubles.

Here is an example of counting lines in a text file using C++:

```
std::ifstream text_file(/*...*/);
std::string   text_from_file;
unsigned int  line_count = 0;
while (std::getline(text_file, '\n'))
{
  ++line_count;
}
```

**When comparing performance, the functionality has to be equivalent.**

**Edit 1:**
*Decide.*  Are you counting lines?

Are you counting the number of rows in a matrix?

Do you want to **only** count the lines in a file?

If you want to count the number of rows in a matrix, you need to modify your Perl script.

If you want the MEX function to **only** count lines, remove everything but the call to `countlines` function.

Why are you using a `double` for the line count?
Are you expecting a fractional line count?

Do you want to use C I/O or C++ I/O?

Reading data in blocks will speed up your C I/O function:

```
#define MAX_CHUNK_SIZE 1024*1024
char buffer[MAX_CHUNK_SIZE];
size_t chars_read = 0;
unsigned int line_count = 0;
//...
while (!feof(inputFile))
{
  chars_read = fread(buffer, 1, MAX_CHUNK_SIZE, input_file);
  char c;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < chars_read; ++i)
  {
     if (c == '\n')
     {
       ++line_count;
     }
  }
}
```

The bottleneck in accessing files is the overhead of locating the data.  Reading in larger quantities reduces the overhead.

Comment: I'm only counting lines in a file, not the number of rows in a matrix. I'm using a double for the line count because MATLAB yields a double output for the other approach; it's a good catch, I will try switch it to an `unsigned long long` which should have faster operations then cast it back to a double before return. The UNIX command seems difficult to beat, but let me test out your recommendation as I still want a fast way of doing this on Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this bit of code to count the total number of lines. But it will take the several minis.

```
my $lines = do {
    open my $fh, '<', "filename" or die "Can't open filename: $!";
    1 while (<$fh>);
    $.
};
print "Total number of lines: $lines\n";
```

Comment: @Miller: Scalar also count the total number of the lines then why you use while condition.?

Comment: That will attempt to load the entire file into memory.  Given the OP is talking about a 10gig file, that probably is going to run out of space and end up caching.  Basically, unless there is a specific reason why someone wants to have the entire file in memory, one should always lean toward line by line processing.

Answer (score 0):

to count lines efficiently, just do the following:

```
int main()
{
   unsigned long lines = 0;
   int c; /* c must be an int, not char */

   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
      if (c == '\n') 
         lines++;
   printf("%lu\n", lines);
   return 0;
} /* main */
```

I think there's a similar example in Kernighan & Ritchie, if not the same.  And please, don't use a `double` to count next time.  It's far more efficient to count with integer types thant with floating point numbers.

Comment: This is not efficient because you are reading one character at a time into a variable.  That means you are calling the OS, telling the hard drive to spin up, read one byte, then spin down and have the OS return the value.  Hard drives like to fetch lots of data at once.  So reading 1 megabyte into memory is more efficient than 1 meg of calls to read 1 byte.  The hard drive overhead is the same in each case.  Try it out.

Comment: Not.  You are wrong.  STDIO buffers in chunks of BUFSIZ size, so you are only **processing** each character at a time.  In case I were doing `while (read(&c, 1, 0) == 1)` I would be reading a character at a time, but that's not the case.  Have a look at K&R first.  Even in case you read from a terminal, stdio buffers all the line and processes characters one at a time with getchar(); This pushes on controversy to newbies who try to read a character at a time using getchar() and look for an alternative in curses.h getch()

Comment: Let us take a close example, print the assembly code.  As you will notice, there is a branch statement for each read of one character. So for reading 1000 characters, there will be 1000 function calls.  Using `fread` to read 1000 characters results in 1 function call.  Also, the OP is reading files and `getchar()` reads from `stdin`.  Again, time it.  I did.  This is how I saved more than 5 minutes reading large files.

Comment: BTW, look up the size of `BUFSIZ`.  Is it 1 megabyte?  Is it 512?  With reading into your own buffer, you can change the size to greater than `BUFSIZ`.  And the command would be `fread(buffer, 1, 1024 * 512, file);`  or using C++: `read(buffer, 1024 * 512)`.  I don't know where you got your syntax for reading.

Comment: of course you can also set you own buffer and use it for the stdio functions. I'm not going to enter in the debate...  it's not my way of reading characters, it's the one Kernighan uses in his book.  Getchar is normally defined also as a macro, calling to fgetch for the character.  BUFSIZ is optimized to the block size of the system, and no standar forces it to be 512.  Of course, you can use whatever function you like.  But I think you'll not win the prize.  I'm not goint to print the assembly code, as this question is a general language one, not a particular compiler implementation issue.

Comment: by the way, have you seen the assembler output? have you compared the running times of `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` against `while (read(0, &c, 1) == 1)` ??? I think you haven't done that.